# D3: Directional graph similar to tree layout but with back links

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, d3.js

I am looking for layout in d3 which allow to layout nodes in directional graph as shown in [Collapsible Tree example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) but the twist is that the directional graphs which I need to plot has converging links also. Its basically MANY-TO-ONE and then ONE-TO-MANY graph and there can be back links/edges as well.

As, I just know the nodes and transitions but not the location of nodes, I was just wondering if D3 can layout this using any existing layout like graphViz does it for digraphs.

Comment: AFAIK there's no layout like this in D3.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I am trying to use force layout with fixed nodes and assigning locations to these nodes using custom algorithm for layout. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: It sounds like you wouldn't need the force layout for this.

Comment: Any better alternative?

Comment: From what you said it sounds like you're making your own layout and wouldn't need any of the D3 layouts.

Comment: Yes. I don't think there is any option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be NO d3 layout to be used directly. Instead, the approach which I have adopted is:

1. Group all the nodes as per depth from source node.
2. Sort the nodes at particular level according to the nodes in previous level so as to minimize crossings.
3. Layout all nodes at a level with same X but different Y coordinates.

This works for me for the cases I am trying to address.